# Solving for eigenvectors of an eigenvalues

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

$A=\begin{bmatrix}
a & 0\\ 
 0& b
\end{bmatrix}$

The eigenvalues are $\lambda_{1}=a,\lambda_{2}=b$

To solve for the corresponding eigenvectors for eigenvalue $\lambda_{1}=a$:

We solve $A\vec{v}_{1}=\lambda_{1}\vec{v}_{1}$

$\begin{bmatrix}
0 &0 \\ 
 0& d-a
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v_{1,1}\\ 
v_{1,2}
\end{bmatrix}$=$\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0
\end{bmatrix}$

I understand this is a simple question and I have no reasons to doubt the theory on hand but for some reason I am not yielding the correct eigenvectors.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Even without going through the long process, what can you say happens to $[1,0]^T$ and $[0,1]^T$ when multiplied by $A$?  Note: for the longer traditional way there are two different cases to consider, when $a=b$ and when $a\neq b$.  In the first case $A-aI$ is the zero matrix and so rowreduces to the zero matrix implying both entries are free variables for solution vector.  In the second case $A-aI$ row reduces to $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ implying the second entry is zero and implies nothing about the first entry meaning it is free to be any value.

Comment: It is just the component of the vector multiplied by a constant A.

Comment: $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}a&0\\0&b\end{smallmatrix}\right]\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right] = \left[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]=a\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1\\0\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, and what is the definition of an eigenvector?  You should be able to show rather straightforwardly that the eigenvectors of any diagonal matrix are the standard basis vectors.

Comment: The system you arrive at reduces to $(b-a)v_{1,2}=0$, that is, if $b\ne a$, $v_{1,2}=0$, that is, $\vec v_1$ colinear to $(1,0)^T$. Where is the mystery here?

Comment: It’s a bit hard to help you when you haven’t told us the results of *your* calculations that you say come out incorrectly.

Comment: @Did Can you explain the part about collinearity?  A bit an LA refresher would be helpful.

Comment: ?? Please read http://math.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask, say: "Your questions should be reasonably scoped. If you can imagine an entire book that answers your question, you’re asking too much."